# Max array size in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I am programming in Kotlin via Android Studio 3.1.3. I created an array of type Long that was apparently too large to compile. After playing around with it for a while, I found that the maximum size array I could get to compile contained 8,207 elements. An array with 8,208 or more elements caused a compilation error. There are 350 lines of elements in the array, which contains prime numbers in numerical order. Two questions:

1. Does anyone have any idea why this limit would exist?  8,208 is (2^13 + 2^4), but that seems like an odd tipping point.  So, I doubt that is the reason for the limitation.
2. Is there any way to increase the allowed size of the array?

Note: On the Android forum, it was suggested that I use ArrayList instead of ArrayLong.  I appreciate that suggestion and intend to try it, but the limitation on a Long Array still seems odd to me.  If anyone has a more elegant solution or an explanation for the limit, I would love to hear it!  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show your code and the precise error you get.  Array size should certainly not cause compile errors.

Comment: @Earl Whitney *There are 350 lines of elements in the array* you mean editor lines?

Comment: The code looks like this:  val primes: LongArray = longArrayOf(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 ... 84143, 84163, 84179, 84181, 84191). The exact error is: java.lang.illegalStateException:Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation. Cause: error generating class file primeskt class ...

Comment: By 350 lines of elements, i mean in the Primes.kt file, the 8,207 elements take up 350 lines in the editor.  That probably has nothing to do with the error, but I wanted to give as much info as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what you're trying to do is something like:

```
var a = longArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...)
```

There's a limitation by JVM. Maximum size of method is 64K.

If you decompile your code, you'll receive something like that for each element in the array:

```
DUP
SIPUSH 8206
LDC 8207
LASTORE
```

And that's where you hit the limit.

Comment: if the OP's testing was right: 8207 elements x 8 bytes per Long = 65656 bytes which exceeds 64K=65536 bytes.

Comment: If you're really interested, you can take a look at the bytecode. There are some optimizations compiler is doing, like using constants for the first few numbers, using int cache for numbers below 128, and so on.

Comment: I'm sure this have to do with a limit. It can't be a coincidence that 65656 is so close to 64K. These are extreme cases but it's good to know

Comment: I didn't say that it's a coincidence. What I said is that my calculation is not absolutely precise, but should be good enough to answer this probably trolling question.

Comment: I admit to being surprised by the limit; thank you for letting me know about that.  I suppose I can double the size of the array by using Int instead of Long, and using toLong when I use the primes[i] values.  My question is not trolling.   I am new to this.  I apologize if my question upset anyone.

Comment: Then I apologize. But you must understand that you're doing something wrong if you're creating a literal array of thousands of hardcoded elements.

Comment: I attempted to change the size of the array by using Int instead of Long.  With this change, i am able to increase the size of the array to 8,240 Int elements.  With 8,241 or more I get the same compile error.

Comment: I'm using a large array of literals in order to cut down on processing time. I'm trying to spark interest in math for high schoolers and they tend to push the limits of anything presented to them.  i want the app to be lightning fast and to be able to find the prime factorization of very large numbers.  Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Just to say it, thank you very much for your help!  I use this site a lot to make up for my lack of training.  People like you make it possible for people like me to do things we would otherwise not be able to do.  And, i hope a lot of kids will be  excited by what my apps will show them.

Comment: I suggest putting them in a file then doing `File("./your-file.txt").useLines {}`